# Algorithm using O(log^2 N) running time?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I have edited this question in hope that this question can be re-opened.

First of all, this was part of an assignment.

I was asked to write a method with a running time in proportion to O(log² N).

log² N should not be equal to log N² as there is another similar question in my assignment for log N².

I have searched and look through previous questions but I couldn't find any topic talking about log² N.

My guess for log² N will be that it is a nested for-loops of log n:

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i*=2){
  for(int j=0; j < n; j*=2){
   //some code here...
  }
}
```

However, it does not really justify a good answer as this code could also represent log N².

Therefore, I hope some of you can give me some guidance regarding log² N or maybe an example of an algorithm that might be running in O(log² N)

I hope this has make my question clearer and thus allowing this question to be re-opened.

Comment: It is a matter of definition. Some regard log^2(n) as log(log(n)) and some as log(n) * log(n).

Comment: @Y.Shoham not necessary. It could just as well be `log(log(n))`. The notation of `f^k(x)` for f applied k times onto x is also *very* common. Because you can use `log(n)^2` for the other one. Why would you write `log^2(x)` if you could write `log(x)^2` and have it less ambiguous?

Comment: In all the algorithms development I've seen, it's almost always used to refer to log n * log n.

Comment: Yes, it often is `log^2(n)=log(n)^2`, however I'd like to beat everyone on the head that uses the first notion, as it *could* also mean `log log n`, and the other doesn't have this problem and is not longer.

Comment: I'd like to add [a source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Exponential_notation_for_function_names). Also, the notation `log(n)^2` cannot always be used: sometimes you need a "point-free" representation, e.g. in the expression `log^2 ∘ sin`, where `∘` represents composition of functions. This is the function that maps `x` to `log(sin(x))^2`, but sometimes one does not want to explicitly state the name `x`, for example to unambiguously note derivatives using the [D operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_operator). Avoiding confusion is always good, though!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would have a complexity of `O(n) = log^2(n)`:

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2)
{
    for(int j = 1; j < n; j = j * 2)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean "Something like this is O(log^2(n))" -- saying "O(n) = log^2(n)" is nonsense.  But anyway, infinite loops like those are neither  O(log^2(n)) nor O(n), they are O(infinity).

Comment: This is written under the assumption that the code in the loops, denoted by "//Code" has a complexity of O(n) = 1.

Comment: I don't see `O(n) = 1` making any sense.

Comment: They still are infinite loops.  `for(int i = 0; i < n; i = i * 2)` never sets i to anything but 0

Comment: Sorry I meant for i and j to be equal to 1 at first, that was a typo.  Also, O(n) = 1 means that your code runs in constant time.

Comment: Saying "O(n) = 1 means that your code runs in constant time" is nonsense; that isn't how the terminology works.  If code runs in constant time, it is O(1).